# getting error "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object"

Tags: apex, visualforce

There are two objects student_details__c and department__c. department__c - contains name and no_of_students__c; student_details__c contains name, department(lookup to department object).

when a student is inserted in a department, that respective department needs to increment the no_of_students__field,similarly when department is changed of a student from one dept to other then no_of_students__c needs to be incremented in the new department and decremented from the old department field. no_of_student__c is the total count of students in respect to the department the belong to in each department object.

There maybe other ways to accomplish this,but need to create a trigger for this at the moment.

I dont know why it is giving me error,it is

Trigger

```
trigger Deptnumberupdate on Student_Details__c (after insert, after update,after delete) {

    studentchangeshandler studobj = new studentchangeshandler();
    if(trigger.isinsert)
    {
    studobj.afterinsert(trigger.new);
    }

    if(trigger.isupdate)
    {
    studobj.afterupdate(trigger.new );
    }    
}
```

Trigger Handler

```
public class studentchangeshandler{



         public void afterupdate(student_details__c[] newstudList , map<id,sobject> oldstudlist) {

         set<id> Deptids = new set<id>();

         for(student_Details__c record: newstudlist){

            Deptids.add(record.Department__c);
            }


        list<department__c> deptlist = [select id,name,no_of_students__c,(select id from student_details__r) from department__c where id in:Deptids];


     for(department__c dept : deptlist){

               if (dept.Name == 'CSE')
                   {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c +1;
                    }

                else if (dept.Name == 'ECE')
                {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c +1;
                   }
                else if (dept.Name == 'IT')
                   {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c +1;
                   }

                else if (dept.Name == 'EEE')
                {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c +1;
                   }

            }       

            for(department__c dept : deptlist){       
                  for(Student_details__c student : dept.student_details__r){
        Student_details__c oldStud = (student_details__c)Trigger.oldMap.get(student.ID);





             //student_details__c oldstud = (student_details__c)oldstudlist.get(dept.ID);
                       if (oldstud.department__c == 'CSE')
                   {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c -1;


                   }

                else if (dept.Name == 'ECE')
                {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c -1;
                   }
                else if (dept.Name == 'IT')
                   {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c -1;
                   }

                else if (dept.Name == 'EEE')
                {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c -1;
                   }

            }       


  update deptlist;   

 }



}
}
```

getting error

> **Error: Invalid Data.** Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger Deptnumberupdate caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: Deptnumberupdate: execution of AfterUpdate
>   caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null
>   object: Class.studentchangeshandler.afterupdate: line 89, column 1 at line 
>   student_details__c oldstud = (student_details__c)Trigger.oldMap.get(dept.ID);

Answer (score 5):

`Trigger.oldMap` is Map of `student_details__c` object and not `department__c` object. So, you are trying to fetch wrong value.

Also, this map is returning a null value which you are trying to typecast to `student_details__c` object.

Comment: I am trying to get the student_detail__c record which is related to the department__c.how could I make this method work?

Answer (score 5):

Problem is with this line:

```
student_details__c oldstud = (student_details__c)Trigger.oldMap.get(dept.ID);
```

`Trigger.oldMap` has mapping with the `id` of a `Student_details__c` and you're trying to get it with `dept.Id`. This will return `null` since department `Id`'s are different from `Student_details__c` id.

Your problem can be solve like this:

```
// Iterate related list of Student associated deptList 
for(department__c department:deptlist) {
    for(Student_details__c student : department.student_details__r){
        Student_details__c oldStudent = (student_details__c)Trigger.oldMap.get(student.ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62215/discussion-on-answer-by-rohit-mourya-getting-error-system-nullpointerexception).